# How to launch two sql queries using result of first one in second?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 queries and i want to use result of first query in second one.
Following does not work for me:

```
$id     = $_GET['uid'];
$app_id = $_GET['apid'];
$sql    = "insert into tbl_sc (client_id,status) values ($id,1)";
mysql_query($sql) or die ($sql);
$result = mysql_insert_id();
echo $result;

$sql    = "insert into tbl_ms(m_name, ng_ID, status)
           values ($app_id,$result ,1)";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die ($sql);
```

Is there any other way to get same result?

Comment: The return value of mysql_query(), i.e. $result is a resource - what (ie. which data type) do you want to insert into tbl_ms?

Comment: first ``$result`` is only a resource. Unless you want to use that ``mysql_insert_id()``..

Comment: @EugenRieck First `$result` variable here is not a resource. Though second one is.

Comment: How it should work? Did you try  renaming the first `$result` to `$insert_id` ?

Comment: @hia: Do you want the auto-generated by MySQL Primary Key of `tbl_sc` from the first insert statement to be used in the second insert?

Comment: @Shiplu Sure you are right - any way it is not what the OP expected it to be

Comment: HOW IT SHOULD WORK: it does echo autogenerated key and in second querry it inserts in tabel. 
it will be local runned android program communicating with local webserver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have used MySQL [LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) function.  This way all this mess with insert id will be gone.

```
$sql    = "insert into tbl_sc (client_id,status) values ($id,1)";
if(mysql_query($sql)){
    $sql    = "insert into tbl_ms(m_name, ng_ID, status)
               values ($app_id, LAST_INSERT_ID() ,1)";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if($result){
        // Process your result
    }else{
        // second query failed!
        die (mysql_error());
    }
}else{
    // first query failed!
    die (mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: This is fine but sometimes, one has to deal with mess anyway. Like if first INSERT succeeds and second fails (and you need to know the last-insert_id in your code, e.g. to retry)

Comment: @ypercube right you are. Updated the code a little bit for that.

Comment: Thanks for feedback!
I found error.. 
$sql = "insert into tbl_ms(m_name, ng_ID, status)
values ('$app_id',$result ,1)";

I had to quote '$app_id'.. while testing i was passing integer and in ap I passed a string    
And because I was using app debugger I did not see the real error...

Answer (score 1):

`$result` contains an SQL resource, not the id.

```
$insert_id = mysql_insert_id();
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_ms(m_name, ng_ID, status) 
        VALUES ($app_id, $insert_id, 1)";
```

Don't forget to sanitize user input to avoid injection attacks.

Comment: in my case it contains a autogenerated number, and ng_ID is olso int value.

Answer (score 1):

`$result` in your code will always contain a boolean, and if it was successful, when used in the next query, this will always be `1`. You `echo`d the value you need, but you didn't catch it in a variable so it could be used in the next query.

Try this:

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['uid']);
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_sc
          (client_id, status)
        VALUES
          ($id, 1)";
mysql_query($sql) or die ("MySQL error with query ( $sql ): ".mysql_error());

$app_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['apid']);
$insertId = mysql_insert_id();
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_ms
          (m_name, ng_ID, status) 
        VALUES
          ($app_id, $insertId ,1)";
mysql_query($sql) or die ("MySQL error with query ( $sql ): ".mysql_error());
```

You **MUST** escape user input before using it in a query - you don't want a visit from [Bobby Tables](http://www.bobby-tables.com/)...

Comment: *`$result` in your code will always contain a boolean*. Wrong! it'll contain false if no result is found. Otherwise it'll contain result resource.

Comment: @Shiplu True, if this was a query that returned a result set. It will be boolean for an `INSERT`...

Comment: Hello everybody and thanks for such a quick replay. 
What it shold do is: first to echo mysql_insert_id() (it sends me back what i need) and then it should register my result in second table.

Comment: this one didnot work.. again first querry gives result, but second is not runned...

Answer (score 1):

Make a variable `$insertedID = mysql_insert_id();` just before the second `$sql` variable !
And in the second `$sql` query replace the `$result` with `$insertedID`

It should solve your problem !

Answer (score 1):

In the second query just use

```
insert into tbl_ms(m_name, ng_ID, status)
           values ($app_id,last_insert_id() ,1)
```

no need to play this via PHP!

Comment: tryed, its not working.. second querry does not insert any data :(

Comment: echo the SQL and post it, best include a DESCRIBE tbl_ms

Comment: what do you mean by DESCRIBE tbl_ms?

Comment: run the SQL "DESCRIBE tbl_ms" against the databse and post the output

Comment: I checked again my database table. When i run this querrys one by one. it works, but in my combination, its not working.
insert into tbl_ms(m_name, ng_ID, status)
           values (1 ,1 ,1)"
inserts given data to database from code...

Comment: m_name is Text;
ng_ID  is int(10);
status is tinyint (4);
prim   is int (11)autoincrement prim key;